# Need help C++ please, using bool etc

Tags: c++

My task is: to write a program which reads characters one by one from the keyboard until the character ’q’ is
entered. Use a loop with and bool variable for exiting the loop. At the end a string containing
all entered letter should be printed on the screen (except the ’q’).

This is what i have so far and i am kind of stuck now, everytime i run it I am only able enter 1 character then the program stops---> this occurred after i wrote the last line with if(b==true)....... .

```
int main()
{
bool b;
char input[80];
int i;

b = false;
while(b != true){
    cout<<"Enter characters: "<<endl;
    cin>>input[i];
    if(input[i] == 'q'){
        b == true;
        break;
    }
}

if(b == true){
    for(int j = 0; j < 1; j++){
        for(int x = 0; x < 1; x++){
            cout<<input[i]<<endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Please help. Thank you very much.

Comment: You haven't initialized `i` and you aren't event incrementing it.

Comment: `b == true; ` does nothing you need = not ==. What is the b == statement after the loop? b will always be true, once you actually assign to it. Why are you using break? The while statement will already stop when you set b to true. What is the j for loop? It only does ever does the loop once, and the same for the x loop, which should be looping i times. Why not just assign '\0' to input[i] after the while loop and do cout << input?

Comment: Note that you don't have to do `while (b != true)`. Instead you can just write `while (!b)`.

Answer (score 2):

Six bugs.

1. You forgot to initialize `i` to zero.
2. You forgot to increment `i` on each pass of the loop
3. Operator `==` is different than operator `=`.
4. Bad things will happen if your input exceeds the size of your input
   array.  Hence, some checks to make sure `i` does not exceed `80` (the declared length of your input array.
5. You are inserting `q` into the `input` array, but you don't want to print it.
6. Prompting for more characters on each iteration of the loop. Not sure if you meant this.

Some modifications to your loop:

```
i = 0;
b = false;
cout<<"Enter characters: "<<endl;
while (i < 80)  // limit to 80 chars
{
    char ch;
    cin >> ch;
    if(ch == 'q')
    {
        b = true;   // assign with =, not compare with ==
        break;
    }
    input[i] = ch; // insert into array after the check for q
    i++;  // increment i
}
```

Finally, your print loop is hopeless. Let's just safely null terminate your string and print it.

```
if(b)
{
    if (i >= 80)
    {
        i=79;
    }
    input[i] = '\0';
    cout << input << endl;
}
```

If you are familiar enough with the string class in C++, you could easily convert your code to use that. Then you won't have to deal with array limits of 80.

Comment: Thank you so much. But I still do not understand the code fully
this part, could you explain this part:
if(b)....

Comment: `if (b)` is equivalent to `if (b != false)` which is a near equivalent expression to `if (b == true)`

Answer (score 0):

use this code it will work as you wish.

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::cin;

int main()
{
    char input[80];
    int i = 0;

    input[i] = cin.get();

    while (input[i] != 'q')
    {
        i++;
        input[i] = cin.get();
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
    {
        cout << input[j];
    }

    system("Pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This solution will crash (or generate unexpected results) if the input string exceeds 80 chars.